# Localization at the Johnson-Wilson spectrum and rationalization

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, chromatic-homotopy

Is there a clean proof that the $L_n$, localization at $E(n)$, is simply rationalization (i.e. $L_0$) on Eilenberg-MacLane spectra? Eric Peterson asked this [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19941162#19941162), but I haven't seen an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, recall that any rational spectrum is a wedge of suspended copies of $H\mathbb{Q}$.  It follows that $H\mathbb{Q}$ is a retract of $E(n)\mathbb{Q}$ and so is $E(n)$-local.  From this we see that the canonical map $H\to H\mathbb{Q}$ factors uniquely through $L_nH$.

Over $\pi_*(E(n)\wedge H/p)$ we have a formal group law $F$ coming from $E(n)$, and a formal group law $G$ coming from $H$ (which is just $x+_Gy=x+y$).  These are isomorphic, by the standard yoga of complex oriented cohomology theories.  We have $[p]_G(x)=0$, and it follows easily that $[p]_F(y)=0$.  However, we also have $[p]_F(y)=\sum^F_{0\leq k\leq n}v_ky^{p^k}$, so $v_k=0$ in $\pi_*(E(n)\wedge H/p)$ for all $k$.  But $v_n$ is invertible, so $E(n)\wedge H/p=0$.  It follows that $L_n(H/p)=0$.  But $L_n(H/p)$ is the cofibre of $p$ times the identity on $L_nH$, so we see that $p.1_{L_nH}$ is an equivalence, so $L_nH$ is rational.  It follows that the canonical map $H\to L_nH$ factors through a map $H\mathbb{Q}\to L_nH$.  This is inverse to the map $L_nH\to H\mathbb{Q}$ that we exhibited earlier.